# NullPointerException when trying to build a list from a file

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to build an ArrayList from a text file using following code:

```
while (true) {
                String a = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println(a);
                if (a.equals("<<--- [[ list ENDS HERE ]] --->>")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    this.list.add(a);
                }
            }
```

For some reason the code prints the first string to the console, but when it tries to add it to the list I get a NullPointerException.

The list starts from the beginning of the file and the building should stop when a line that reads "<<--- [[ list ENDS HERE ]] --->>" is read by the code.

Here's what it prints to the console:

```
First string
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at fi.kynis.Engine.buildList(Engine.java:43)
at fi.kynis.Engine.start(Engine.java:22)
at fi.kynis.KKClient.main(KKClient.java:11)
```

As requested: Line 43:

```
this.list.add(a);
```

The odd thing over here is that it is perfectly able to print the first string, but it can't add it to the ArrayList. So do any of you more wiser coders have a solution to this.

Comment: Need more info is the code you are providing the code at fi.kynis.Engine.buildList(Engine.java:43)? Which line number is 43?

Comment: I think your list variable is null  you should use list=new ArrayList<String>() or any otther collection constructor before you add anything in your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` is null.

You need to do:

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Before adding elements to the list.

Comment: Thanks... I actually forgot to add that. On an earlier line I had typed 'private ArrayList<String> list;'